# How to use Q Classes of Querydsl?

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

I want to use **QueryDSL** with **JPA** and I plugged in **apt-maven** successfully.

**Pom.xml;**

```
     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor </processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Also it generated the Q classes of domain classess successfully too but when I  `import com.buraku.netas.domain.QUser;` , it throws an error and can't find Q classes.

Here's how my folder structure looks like after I run **mvn install**;

[image]

As you see Q classes are generated but what else should I do to use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add implements `QuerydslPredicateExecutor<User>` to interface `UserRepository`.

Second, create a method which returns `com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate` and build a query(JPQL) using `BooleanBuilder` and `Q-classes`.

You might refer to my sample-jpa code on github.

[jpa-sample-code](https://github.com/starrybleu/jpa-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/idincu/sample/jpa/api/spec/SamplePredicates.java)

Comment: But I can't use Q-classes as those Q-classes throws an error saying couldn't be found. I did first thing you said and run mvn clear install but it still doesn't let me to import Q-classes

Comment: By the way, could you please share you pom.xml on github?

Comment: I didn’t use maven but gradle. But I found your problem which is wrong with your outputDirectory. It should be “src/main/generated_sources/“. Or add your current outputDirectory into classpath.

Comment: Take a look in my build.gradle which points sourceSets with “src/main/java” and “src/main/generated”. It can be a hint. Maybe you need to find a equivalent expression for maven from this.